# Create dictionary from several lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I'd like to create a dictionary considering several lists, I've checked that the most common way is to use zip function. However, I think it does not apply in my case.

Suppose you have a list of name and two additional lists which store nouns and verbs. So each item in the list name has to be categorized based on the list it appears (noun or verb). I have something like the following:

```
import collections

noun=['abc','school']
verb=['study','read']

name=['abc','study','read','school']

d=collections.OrderedDict()

for word in name:
    if word in noun:
        d.update({word:'noun'})
    else:
        d.update({word:'verb'})


print("Modified Dict : ")
for (key, value) in d.items() :
    print(key , ":", value )
```

I imagine this can be done in a more optimized way. Just I do not know how it would be.

Thanks

Comment: You could do `d={word: 'noun' if word in noun else 'verb' for word in name}` (this is an ordinary dictionary, then, of course)

Comment: @DavidWierichs answered. Also note that you don't need parenthesis at (key, value) and that from python 3.6, dict respect the insertion order, so you don't need to use OrderedDict() explicitly if you're using python 3.6 and need to rely on insertion order (which is uncommon)

Answer (score 0):

You already got answer in comment how to do it with dict comprehension.

I show how to make your code more universal.

You could keep `nous`, `verb` in dictionary and then you can use `key,val` with one `if`.

This way you can add new categories in dictionary `data` and rest of code is the same.

```
data = {
    'noun': ['abc','school'],
    'verb': ['study','read'],
    'stopword': ['at','or'],
}    

name = ['abc', 'study', 'read', 'school', 'at', 'or']

d = {}

for word in name:
    for key, value in data.items():
        if word in value:
            d.update({word: key})

for key, value in d.items():
    print(key, ":", value )
```